# How can I fix this error

Tags: javascript, php

I am learning php from w3school and I am trying to run this code but there is shown an error when I click submit button without filling the form. Here goes my code which is in a file named "**form.php**"

```
<html>
<body>
<style type="text/css">

</style>
<h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
<form method="post" action="welcome.php">  
  Name: <input type="text" name="name">
  <br><br>
  E-mail: <input type="text" name="email">
  <br><br>
  Website: <input type="text" name="website">
  <br><br>
  Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
  <br><br>
  Gender:
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is my another file named "**welcome.php**"

```
<?php

  $name = $_POST["name"];
  $email = $_POST["email"];
  $website = $_POST["website"];
  $comment = $_POST["comment"];
  $gender = $_POST["gender"];
    echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
    echo $name;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $email;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $website;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $comment;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $gender;
    ?>
```

But when I submit form without filling the form its shown this.

Notice: Undefined index: gender in C:\xampp\htdocs\self\welcome.php on line 7

Please someone help to find the error............

Comment: Javascript validation on the page itself, PHP validation after you submit. Verify that all fields are filled out.

Comment: Is there any mistake in my code? Why I am seeing this error only for radio button?

Comment: Radio buttons and checkboxes don't exist until they have a selected value.

Comment: Then why this code doesn't show error when I copying this from here http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_form_validation_escapechar

Comment: Some versions of PHP can suppress that error, or don't register it at all. They probably have error messages turned off.

Comment: thanks anyber for your help